# How to stop the favourites pane popping out of the left side of Safari fullscreen?

Tags: macos, safari

This is a frustrating feature and I can't seem to find a setting to remove it.

Safari Version 12.0.1 (14606.2.104.1.1)
Mojave

Comment: Which version of Safari?

Comment: Safari Version 12.0.1 (14606.2.104.1.1)
Mojave

Comment: I can't repro. It stays in the same state as it was before I fullscreen it, whether open or closed.